# Composer.phar update now results in an ErrorException for MonologBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2, monolog

symfony/symfony v2.2.0
monolog/monolog v1.4.1

After running `composer.phar update` yesterday, monolog was updated; running the same command today results in the following error message:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Generating autoload files

  [ErrorException]
  Warning: constant(): Couldn't find constant Monolog\Logger::DEBUG in [path]\vendor\symfony\monolog-bundle\Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\DependencyInjection\MonologExtension.php line 109
```

The (i think) relevant part of config_dev.yml

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        firephp:
            type:  firephp
            level: info
```

Did something change that requires additional configuration, or is something else happening ?

Comment: I have this, but in Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the update didn't go well - do you have a Logger class in `vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php`? If not I would suggest deleting the `vendor/monolog` dir and running composer install to get it back.

Comment: Even worse: I'm getting an access denied message.  Deleting `vendor/monolog` and re-running the update indeed fixed the issue.

Comment: @Seldaek I've tried deleting the repo and installing it back but I still get the exact same error!! And Monolog\Logger::DEBUG exists.

Comment: @Wissem not sure what to tell you, if the constant exist then the class must be ok. Maybe report an issue on github if you can't figure it out, because this is quite vague and not the best place to report detailed information.

Comment: solved it by updating composer: composer self-update

Answer (score 15):

Monolog recently switch to PSR-4 compatible autoloading. Possibly, the 
version of Composer you're running is too old for that. Please run 
composer self-update first and try to update your dependencies again.

Comment: No luck, it says `You are already using composer version X`, but still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same thing, but for *Laravel*.

I solved it by creating the `app/storage` folder and all it's sub-folders and files.

I get them by creating a new empty project, and just a copy-paste !

Woking now...

---

Here is the file structure:

```
app/storage/cache  
app/storage/logs  
app/storage/meta  
app/storage/sessions  
app/storage/views
```

You can ignore this folder for your repository.